# How to show calendar on socket emit inside the page?

Tags: flask, fullcalendar, jinja2, flask-socketio

I've created a small app in `Flask` that allows the users to book on the calendar .

I want just the subscribed user to make an appointment, if the `current_user` is not a subscriber , a message you get in place of the calendar that says 'you must be a subscriber to make a book', otherwise the calendar appears .

Am using `SocketIO` for live changing inside the **DOM** , in my views i've created two separated emits, the first one after the user subscribe and the second is if the user unsubscribed . If he subscribed the calendar should appear immediately and he can make the appointment if unsubscribed the calendar also should disappear the moment that the socket being sent .

Here is my **views.py** for both subscribe and after unsubscribe :

```
@client_route.route('/client/cat-<dir_code>/subscribe/<int:worker_id>', methods=['POST'])
@only_client
@is_active_client
def subscribe_worker(worker_id):

    client = Client.query.filter_by(tele=session.get('client_phone') ,name=session.get('client_logged_in'), family=session.get('client_family')).first_or_404()

    worker = Worker.query.filter_by(id=worker_id).first_or_404()

    if not client.is_subscriber(worker.id):
        client.subscribe(worker.id)
        client.in_chat = True
        db.session.add(client)
        db.session.commit()
        socketio.emit('show_calendar', namespace='/notifications-{}-{}'.format(client.name, client.family)
        )
        return jsonify({'success': Thanks for subscription.'})


@client_route.route('/client/cat-<dir_code>/subscribe/<int:worker_id>', methods=['POST'])
@only_client
@is_active_client
def unsubscribe_worker(worker_id):

    client = Client.query.filter_by(tele=session.get('client_phone') ,name=session.get('client_logged_in'), family=session.get('client_family')).first_or_404()

    worker = Worker.query.filter_by(id=worker_id).first_or_404()

    if client.is_subscriber(worker.id):
        client.unsubscribe(worker.id)
        client.in_chat = False
        db.session.add(client)
        db.session.commit()
        socketio.emit('hide_calendar', namespace='/notifications-{}-{}'.format(client.name, client.family)
        )
        return jsonify({'success': Thanks for subscription.'})
```

Now inside my **template**, i've initialized socketio , here is the code :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/notifications-{{session.get("client_logged_in")}}-{{session.get("client_family")}}');

  socket.on('show_calendar', function(){
    alert('Now you can make a book .');
    $('#show_calendar').html('<div id="calendar"></div>');
  });

  socket.on('hide_calendar', function(){
    console.log('Calendar will be disabled .');
    $('#show_calendar').html('\
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible alert-disappear" role="alert">\
          You have to subscribe to make a book .\
      </div>\
    ');
  });

</script>
```

Last thing the **calendar block** :

```
<div id="schedule" class="column_left wrap">
  <div class="header_block">
    <span>Calendar</span>
  </div>
  <div id="show_calendar">
    {% if client.is_subscriber(worker.id) %}
      <div id="calendar"></div>
    {% else %}
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible alert-disappear" role="alert">
          You have to subscribe to make a book .
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is , if i subscribed , i can see inside the **DOM** the text that says **You have to subscribe to make a book** gets removed and the **calendar div** get placed but the calendar doesn't open i see just an empty white space, after page reloading it appears and i won't that , i want the calendar to appear immediately after i subscribe .

Please any help would be tons appreciated !!!

**Update**

I think there should be a way to load another jquery code that initiate and run the `fullcalendar` with all events and appointments that made by another users !!

Comment: linguistic note: "You have to subscribe to make a book" should correctly be "You have to subscribe to make a booking". Otherwise it is not correct English. (Well, it is, but it has the wrong meaning, suggesting the user is going to create some reading material!)

Comment: "the calendar doesn't open i see just an empty white space,". Where is the code that actually creates the fullCalendar? e.g. `$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ //....etc`? Just showing a div called "calendar" is not creating a calendar object.

Comment: this seems to be a client-side question. Why is it tagged with all server-side tags? I recommend that you look at your JavaScript console for errors, that will probably give you some idea of the problem.

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for the languistic note :), now it works fine, but i have a question, if i clicked unsubscribe , the session still saving the user as a subscriber until you do a refresh page , is there any way to make him unsubscriber the moment i click unsubscribe without needing to reload the page ??

Comment: Oh @Miguel, thanks for your interests sir , i am one of your fans , really appreciated all your efforts :) .

Comment: @makmani I don't know python (I came to the question because of the fullCalendar tag), but I guess in your unsubscribe code, you'd have to remove the client from the session variable?

Comment: Yea, i understand that , but i am a flask junior developer i decided to use flask as my web development framework because its really powerful and flexible , in tags field , i am always typing any thing that relates to the topic, thats why you are seeing this question between fullcalendar topics !

Comment: Answering on your comment , what you have mentioned above that i have to remove the client from the session , if i removed it the client will be logged out, inside unsubscribers table i can see him there, but in session he still a subscriber !!

Comment: @Miguel, sir, inside Javascript console , i see no errors !